# Finding the probability distribution of the sum of geometric distributions?

Tags: probability

X and Y are both geometric distributions with success p. What it the Pr(X+Y=n)

Would I use a convolution with a sum for this? Do I need to define a third random variable?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: yep forgot to mention they are independant variables

Comment: Do you know about MGFs and independence with MGFs?

Comment: @Clarinetist no we haven't learned those.

Comment: Convolution would be the way to go, then, I would think.

Comment: @Clarinetist Do I need to define another random variable i.e. X=Z-Y?

Comment: Something like that. Another question: there are two types of geometric distributions. One is the number of trials until the first success, and the other is the number of failures before the first success. Which one are you working with here?

Comment: @Clarinetist number of trials until first success

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
&\ \Pr(X + Y = n)\\
= &\ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Pr(X=i) \cdot \Pr(Y = n - i \mid X = i) \\
= &\ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\Pr(X = i)\cdot\Pr(Y=n-i) \\
= &\ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p(1-p)^{i-1} \cdot p(1-p)^{n-i-1} \\
= &\ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p^2(1-p)^{n-2} \\
= &(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

From the definition of Geometric Random Variables:

If $X, Y$ are the *independent* counts of trials, from sequences of Bernoulli trials, until first success (with rate $p$), then $X+Y$ would be the count of trials from a sequence of Bernoulli trials until the second success.   We would then be seeking the probability of obtaining exactly one success somewhere among $n-1$ trials, then a second success.

> $$\mathsf P(X+Y=n) = (n-1) p^2 (1-p)^{n-2}~\mathbf 1_{n\in \{2,3,\ldots\}}$$